# when '=' can be used just after 'if' in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have noticed this metod, while looking through ActiveModel::Serializable

```
def as_json(args={})
  if root = args[:root] || options[:root]
    options[:hash] = hash = {}
    options[:unique_values] = {}

    hash.merge!(root => serialize)
    include_meta hash
    hash
  else
    serialize
  end
end
```

and i really dont know how the 'if root =' works... Shouldn't it be 'if root =='?

Comment: this code is copied from here: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/lib/active_model/serializable.rb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if root = args[:root] || options[:root]
```

This will assign the value of `args[:root]` to `root` if `args[:root]` is not `nil`. If it is `nil`, then it will assign `options[:root]` to root. If the final result of `root` is not `nil`, then the first branch of the `if` will be taken. If it is `nil`, then the `else` branch will be taken.

Answer (score 6):

This is valid Ruby. It will assign the value of `args[:root]` (if it's not nil), otherwise it will assign the value of `options[:root]`. The if statement will then evaluate the value of the variable `root`. If `root` is truthy (not `nil` or `false`), the if statement passes, otherwise it will execute the else clause.

Usually one make this more clear by doing:

```
if (root = args[:root] || options[:root])
```

Comment: To expound a little, this is because every statement in Ruby has a return value. `if (root = args[:root])` is just going to evaluate `root = args[:root]`, and then pass the result of that statement (which is the new value of `root`) back to the `if` for truthiness evaluation.